Azure synapse rbac role for debug
I am getting the error below when trying to debug a pipeline within Azure synapse
You do not have required Synapse RBAC permission to perform this action.

Contact a Synapse Administrator for this workspace.

Required permission:

Actions: Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/credentials/useSecret/action

Scope: workspaces/workspace_name/credentials/WorkspaceSystemIdentity

I am not sure what role or permission needs to be assigned other than synapse admin.

Synapse Compute Operator assign this role to you in synapse workspace

I already granted the role with a host of others, but it is still not working.

ERROR:
You do not have required Synapse RBAC permission to perform this action.

Contact a Synapse Administrator for this workspace. Required
permission: Actions:
Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/credentials/useSecret/action Scope:
workspaces/workspace_name/credentials/WorkspaceSystemIdntity

To resolve the above ERROR you will need to The Synapse Credential User role is required to run pipelines and use secrets in credentials and linked services in activities.
The below are the steps:


Synapse Credential User

Runtime and configuration-time use of secrets within credentials and linked services in activities like pipeline runs.
To run pipelines, this role is required, scoped to the workspace system identity.
Reference: Synapse RBAC Roles
